# How to add css in post?

Tags: css, wordpress

I use Wordpress. 
I need to add in my post CSS and I didn`t find any plugins...

Comment: please improve you question. also go back and accept some answers. no one will help you if you don't give back to the community

Comment: Do you need to style the post, or add example CSS code or what? Please make your question more answerable.

Comment: I need unique CSS styling to an individual page. Thanks to Jakub. I use solution "Custom Panel" from http://digwp.com/2010/02/custom-css-per-post/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried inline `style="background: #00ff00;"`?

Or am I not understanding your questions correctly?  You should be able to do inline styles by clicking the `HTML` tab when you create your post.

As I was feeling generous, I did a search for 'wordpress css in post' and got this result:
http://digwp.com/2010/02/custom-css-per-post/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean? If you want to manually style a post, you edit the stylesheet for your theme, usually located in `wordpress/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/`. You can adjust that to your needs.

As for adding CSS *inside* a post, use the [CodeHighlighter plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/code-highlighter/). You enclose your CSS inside of a set of `<pre lang="cpp"></pre>` tags.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you want blog post to be custom(add css to it), you will hardly find any plug-in, but if you plan to do it manually it is not difficult though you have to add css styles to page.php and single.php which are in your active wp theme folder.

see any sandbox theme for clear understanding , i use blueprint framework for wordpress which is easy to customize.